# Php strtotime not sum vaules

Tags: php, time, strtotime

Hello i'm using this code to make a test.

```
 <?php echo date("H:i:s", strtotime('00:00:10') + strtotime('00:00:10')); ?>
```

But the output is '15:32:04' instead of '00:00:20' and i cannot find the solution.

I also try:

`<?php echo gmdate("H:i:s", strtotime('00:00:10') + strtotime('00:00:10')); ?>`

and give me the same output.

Thanks for help

Comment: `echo date("H:i:s", strtotime('00:00:10 + 10 seconds'));`

Comment: strtotime() creates a timestamp value (number of seconds since 00:00:00 UTC on Jan 01 1970) defaulting to the current date if you don't specify a date, which (today) gives `1457305210` for `strtotime('00:00:10')` (ie `2016-03-07 00:00:10`); so you can't simply add those timestamps together unless you force the date to be Jan 01 1970

Comment: `strtotime` returns a timestamp. Adding 2 timestamps means you're not only adding seconds but also years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the dateTime class:
http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

It's a lot simpler once you start using it and you can do almost anything you'd like by calling a function. for example you can add X time to a date object by calling the add function:
http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Bear in mind this class will only exist for you if you have php 5.3 or higher.